# How to connect to H2O Deep Water Docker Image from Python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, h2o

sorry, yet another real beginner question:

I downloaded the H2O Deep Water Docker container as explained in the Deep Water Booklet (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepWaterBooklet.pdf):

```
docker run -it --rm -p 54321:54321 -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD:/host opsh2oai/h2o-deepwater-cpu

java -jar /opt/h2o.jar
```

I started H2O successfully and can access it with Flow UI in my local browser via localhost:54321.

I want to do the MNIST Python example from the above booklet. I use Anaconda and Spyder IDE with Python 2.7.

I think instead of using init(), I assume I have to use the connect() method. Either way does not work, I get TimeOut, Connection Error or HTTP Exception depending on what I try... I tried several IPs (including localhost), e.g.:

```
from h2o.estimators.deepwater import H2ODeepWaterEstimator
# Start or connect to H2O
#h2o.init()
h2o.connect(ip="127.0.0.1", port=54321)
```

My startup logs show the following.

```
root@d54b0501b7c1:/# java -jar /opt/h2o.jar
08-11 08:46:32.904 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Found XGBoost backend with library: xgboost4j
08-11 08:46:32.926 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
08-11 08:46:32.928 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Build git branch: (HEAD detached at 0c917c766)
08-11 08:46:32.928 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Build git hash: 0c917c766f28860a19ff3f110e1f405eb9f41623
08-11 08:46:32.928 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-master-3971
08-11 08:46:32.928 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Build project version: 3.13.0.356 (latest version: 3.14.0.1)
08-11 08:46:32.928 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Build age: 12 days
08-11 08:46:32.929 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
08-11 08:46:32.929 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Built on: '2017-07-29 13:31:58'
08-11 08:46:32.929 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.929 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.929 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.929 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.930 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.930 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.930 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: XGBoost Build git branch: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.930 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: XGBoost Build git hash: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.930 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: XGBoost Build git describe: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.930 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: XGBoost Build project version: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.931 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: XGBoost Built by: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.931 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: XGBoost Built on: (unknown)
08-11 08:46:32.931 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Processed H2O arguments: []
08-11 08:46:32.931 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 2
08-11 08:46:32.931 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 31.0 MB
08-11 08:46:32.932 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 444.5 MB
08-11 08:46:32.932 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0_131 (from Oracle Corporation)
08-11 08:46:32.932 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: []
08-11 08:46:32.932 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: OS version: Linux 4.9.36-moby (amd64)
08-11 08:46:32.932 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 1.95 GB
08-11 08:46:32.932 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1502441188713
08-11 08:46:32.933 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: User name: 'root'
08-11 08:46:32.933 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: IPv6 stack selected: false
08-11 08:46:32.933 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth0 (eth0), 172.17.0.2
08-11 08:46:32.933 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
08-11 08:46:32.933 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: H2O node running in unencrypted mode.
08-11 08:46:32.943 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Internal communication uses port: 54322
08-11 08:46:32.943 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Listening for HTTP and REST traffic on http://172.17.0.2:54321/
08-11 08:46:32.945 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: H2O cloud name: 'root' on /172.17.0.2:54321, discovery address /225.53.128.226:57653
08-11 08:46:32.946 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: If you have trouble connecting, try SSH tunneling from your local machine (e.g., via port 55555):
08-11 08:46:32.946 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO:   1. Open a terminal and run 'ssh -L 55555:localhost:54321 root@172.17.0.2'
08-11 08:46:32.946 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO:   2. Point your browser to http://localhost:55555
08-11 08:46:32.955 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Log dir: '/tmp/h2o-root/h2ologs'
08-11 08:46:32.957 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Cur dir: '/'
08-11 08:46:33.072 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: HDFS subsystem successfully initialized
08-11 08:46:33.085 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: S3 subsystem successfully initialized
08-11 08:46:33.088 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Flow dir: '/root/h2oflows'
08-11 08:46:33.142 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Cloud of size 1 formed [/172.17.0.2:54321]
08-11 08:46:33.166 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Registered parsers: [GUESS, ARFF, XLS, SVMLight, AVRO, PARQUET, CSV]
08-11 08:46:33.167 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Watchdog extension initialized
08-11 08:46:33.168 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: XGBoost extension initialized
08-11 08:46:33.171 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Registered 2 core extensions in: 341ms
08-11 08:46:33.172 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Registered H2O core extensions: [Watchdog, XGBoost]
08-11 08:46:33.184 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Found XGBoost backend with library: xgboost4j
08-11 08:46:33.702 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Registered: 160 REST APIs in: 529ms
08-11 08:46:33.711 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Registered REST API extensions: [XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4]
08-11 08:46:34.073 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Registered: 230 schemas in 354ms
08-11 08:46:34.073 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: H2O started in 5343ms
08-11 08:46:34.073 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: 
08-11 08:46:34.075 172.17.0.2:54321      9      main      INFO: Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://172.17.0.2:54321
```

What is the right Python code or missing configuration on my Mac / in the Docker container to connect to this H2O Deep Water Docker container?

Seems to be a security / Docker config issue???

```
h2o.connect(ip="127.0.0.1", port=54321)
Connecting to H2O server at http://127.0.0.1:54321...Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-e78edc3b0d61>", line 1, in <module>
    h2o.connect(ip="127.0.0.1", port=54321)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py", line 74, in connect
    cluster_id=cluster_id, cookies=cookies, verbose=verbose)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 175, in open
    conn._cluster = conn._test_connection(retries, messages=_msgs)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 414, in _test_connection
    cld = self.request("GET /3/Cloud")

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 259, in request
    return self._process_response(resp, save_to)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 574, in _process_response
    data = response.json(object_pairs_hook=H2OResponse)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 877, in json
    self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 352, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 691, in __new__
    if schema == "CloudV3": return H2OCluster.from_kvs(keyvals)

  File "/Users/kai.waehner/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/cluster.py", line 47, in from_kvs
    raise AttributeError("Attribute %s cannot be set on H2OCluster (= %r)" % (k, v))

AttributeError: Attribute internal_security_enabled cannot be set on H2OCluster (= False)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

When you start h2o inside the docker image, and use -p 54321:54321, h2o will be running at localhost:54321 on the machine where you run docker. You can then connect in the normal way with h2o.init(). When init starts it will look for a running h2o -- which you then have -- and connect to it.

Comment: It is not working with "h2o.init()" on my Mac. Error as shown above... There is either something missing or the Docker Image is not configured correctly. FYI: I use Docker Community Edition Version 17.06.0-ce-mac19 (18663) on My Mac OS X 10.12.6...

Comment: I just tried this on my Mac and it was fine. You need to run `docker run -it --rm -p 54321:54321 -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD:/host opsh2oai/h2o-deepwater-cpu`, then go to `http://localhost:54321/flow/index.html` . This shows that H2O is running on the Mac. Then start python, do `import h2o`, `h2o.init(strict_version_check=False)`, which stops it from complaining that you may have the wrong version installed in your Python. Note that your h2o package has to be compatible.

Comment: I have a fresh installation of Anaconda and Python 2.7. H2O version is h2o 3.10.0.9 (shown in 'pip list'). I do exactly the steps you wrote down. I can access the Flow UI. But 'h2o.init(strict_version_check=False)' still shows the errors above. Strange... Which versions are you using? I can do fresh installs and try again... Really need to get this running :-) (I also tried the Github build locally, but too many build exceptions like missing R packages so I stopped trying that after 30min) ... Just need "any kind" of Deep Water running locally.

Comment: I've never seen your error. Your docker image may be old. Run `docker pull opsh2oai/h2o-deepwater-cpu` to get the latest one. Also, I would also recommend you to run Python within the docker image, since then you have the correct python package installed. You do that by putting the h2o in the background: `java -jar /opt/h2o.jar &` . Then do `python` normally and `import h2o`. You should then be good to go. I've tested this and it works fine on a Mac with the latest docker image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Magnus. I can confirm that running Python in the container works - just tried the MNIST example. I am not really happy with this (now I also have to install Spyder within the container to get an IDE, right ?!), but at least I have a working Deep Water example on my laptop now to play around with some examples.

Comment: Great to hear that it works, Kai. You can also run it outside, but you need to have the same Python wheel file that's used on the inside. It usually also works if you have a similar version, meaning with a close version number. This is why I have suggested using strict_version_check=False. Now that you know that it does work you could try this. We also know that it works in flow so you have the correct URL for  H2O running inside the docker image.

Comment: I looked up the exact version of the Python wheel used in the docker image. You can get it here: s3://h2o-deepwater/public/nightly/deepwater-h2o-356/h2o-3.13.0.356-py2.py3-none-any.whl